# Sharepoint Online search / indexing speed

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

when i create a new folder on a Document Library, it takes quite some time for me to be able to search for it from the Search Bar. Is there something that can be done to speed up this process?

Comment: It seems like the expected refresh time is about 15 minutes, sometimes a little faster and sometimes a little slower. We usually create a support case with MS when it exceeds 20 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and in fact there is no SLA on search index freshness/responsiveness. Ultimately you just need to wait for the crawl to complete, whenever it does complete. I'd encourage you to open a support ticket via admin.microsoft.com to see if there are any known issues, make a complaint, etc.

Comment: @Tommy0824 please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!